# Facebook app: Can I view the total number of likes of my app page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to view the total number of likes, and even better, who liked my facebook app profile page? I can't see this option anywhere in the insights.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GraphApi .Take a look here

```
* https://graph.facebook.com/--user id--/likes
```

Search through the person's likes until you find your application id.

More details here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Take a look at this codes https://gist.github.com/783822

Comment: Thanks, but that is only possible if the user is sharing that information, I remember before it was really easy to see how many people liked your page

Comment: It seems to have stopped working as of mid June 2015. It returns `{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}`

Answer (score 0):

Just go on your application profile page. On the left click on "likes this" under the number of people who likes your page.